# Keeping an ASP.net Submit button grayed out UNTIL all Javascript validations are passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I would like to keep a button grayed out (ie. non-clickable) until all javascript (client-side) validations are passed.

First of all, I have set the button's "Enabled" property to false, meaning it is greyed out by default when the page loads.  And oppositely, here is some js code (we always like to see some code) that enables the button:

```
var SubmitButton = document.getElementById('<%=SubmitButton.ClientID %>');
SubmitButton.disabled = false;
```

I have a series of validations taking place in a javascript/jquery block on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Client-Side validation script:
   $(function () {
        $("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
        //Validation logic goes here...
        });
        //etc... there are many more.
   });
</scipt>
```

I guess this is more of a javascript question than anything.  How do I structure my javascript code to accomplish what I want to do here?  **In other words, how, when, and where should I set the disabled property of the button to false in my javascript**?

One thought was to have a function at the end of my script, which contains *all* of the logic from each of my validations, and sets the button to be non-greyed out only if all of the logic passes.  But using this method, there is no code reuse -- I would simply be copy pasting in all of the logic from each validation function into one mega function.  Plus, it would only execute once, which is not good.  The button should be able to be re-grayed-out if they change their input data to be invalid.

After thinking about this for a little while longer than I'd like to admit (such a simple problem :[) why don't I just create a loop at the end of my Javascript that is:

```
while(SubmitButton.disabled = true)
{
    //Perform all validation logic from each validation function -- yes it is painful to reuse all of them again, but it is very straightforward.
    //If all checks pass, then break out of the while loop by setting SubmitButton.disabled = false.
}
```

Comment: You can handle validation on submit button click. Call a function that validates all the fields. If you return false from the function the button click will not submit. Or on the keyup event of all input fields, check if validation passes and then enable button

Comment: I've believe I've got that down :)  That is exactly what I did for my server-side validation.  However, now I am working on client-side validation.  And part of this is graying out the submit button when any field is not filled out properly.  It is totally a structural, logic problem.  Any idea on how to do this in JS?  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Use some validation plugins, they may provide you with some callback options where you can do your button manipulation.

Comment: Personally, I'd take an odd approach.  Function for each val req? cool.  Fire on field exit for dynamic val? cool.  Modify each val function so it writes to an array.  The array holds the field ID that was validated plus the validation result (0/1).

When array holds x elements or the user exits the last field (or whatever logic), a single function is called -- if sum of validation results == 0, all good. If not, loop array, re-firing each validation function if the val result !== 0.

Code reuse. Dynamic val + end of form val. And a nice array to re-val/parse/do whatever with the results!

Comment: Cool solution, I will consider doing it this way if my way ends up being bad.  I'm pursuing the solution I described in the OP right now and will answer my question later as to how i solved this issue (this has got to be a fairly common thing to do).